# Style of addressing attributes in python

Tags: python, coding-style

This question is one of style. Since the attributes are not private in python, is it good and common practice to address them directly outside the class using something like `my_obj.attr`? Or, maybe, it is still better to do it via member-functions like `get_attr()` that is an usual practice in c++?

Comment: You don't use getter methods for simple attributes in Python!

Comment: Usually you won't need a getter for class attribute, only for instance attributes.

Comment: @0xc0de Sorry. I meant object's attributes. I have corrected the question

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sounds like you want to use properties:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, m):
        self._m = m
    @property
    def m(self):
        print 'accessed attribute'
        return self._m
    @m.setter
    def m(self, m):
        print 'setting attribute'
        self._m = m


>>> f = Foo(m=5)
>>> f.m = 6
setting attribute
>>> f.m
accessed attribute
6
```

This is the most adaptive way to access variables, for simple use cases you do not need to do this, and in Python you may always change your design to use properties later at no cost.

Comment: I have never heard of this before. Thank you!

Comment: This answer actually made me understand what the `@property` decorator does. +1 :)

Comment: "you may always change your design to use properties later at no cost." - an important point. Good design in Python is to use normal attributes at first until you discover you need getters and setters. _Then_ you replace it with a property, and client code is none the wiser.

Answer (score 2):

Create an instance of the class first:

```
myinstance = MyClass()
myinstance.attr
```

Otherwise you'd get an error like `AttributeError: class MyClass has no attribute 'attr'` when trying to do `MyClass.attr`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is a common practice. If you want greater control over the way the attributes are retrieved, consider using [`__getattribute__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__) and/or [`__getattr__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__).